# How to store a value of each person through a loop without it being revalued?

Tags: java

So, I have this question to compare which salesman had made more number of sales in total for 3 months each. But I do not know how to store value for each of the salesman in the array as currently it rewrites and only saves the value of the last salesman. Can someone help me out ?

```
       import java.util.Scanner;

        public class TutorialChallenge {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner stringinput = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int size=0;
        int i;
        
        System.out.println("How many salesman are in the company?");
        size = input.nextInt();
        
        String[] salesman = new String[size];
        
        for(i=0;i < size;i++) {
            System.out.println("What is the name of salesman ");
            salesman[i] = stringinput.nextLine();
        }
        for(int j=0; j < size; j++) {
            
            String compare = salesman[j];
        
            for(int k=j+1; k<size;k++) {
                if(compare.equals(salesman[k])){
                    System.out.print("Same name found, " + compare + ".\n");
                }
            }
        }
        
        String[] month = {"January","February","March"};
        int[] carsold = new int[month.length];
        String[] num = new String[size];
        int[] mv = new int[month.length];
        
        for(int a=0; a<size;a++) {
        for(i=0;i<month.length;i++) {
            System.out.println("How many cars did "+salesman[a]+" sold in " + month[i]);

            //How to store value for each of the months for each salesman
        }
        }

        }
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps you should consider creating a Salesman class. Then, each Salesman could be created independently and stored in a List of Salesman objects. Each would have their own sales figures and you could loop through the list to determine which had the highest sales. Good Luck to you.

Comment: Well, in this case, my question states to name the amount of salesmans and their names so I can't make a class with them. Any other ways?

Comment: @SuperJackFTW Why can't you make a class with them? The class should have a name.

Comment: @NomadMaker yes , I can make a class with them, but my question given to me asked me to input names and store it in an array so I couldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem have two different solutions.

1. Create a salesman class, which has name and number of sales for each month.
2. Create 2 dimensional array in length of number of salesmen by number of months, and then store each value in the array, for example:

```
String[] month = {"January","February","March"};
        int[][] carsold = new int[size][month.length];//creating 2 dimensional array. 
        String[] num = new String[size];
        int[] mv = new int[month.length];
        
        for(int a=0; a<size;a++) {
        for(i=0;i<month.length;i++) {
            System.out.println("How many cars did "+salesman[a]+" sold in " + month[i]);

            carsold[a][i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        }
```

Finally, if you haven't particular reason for using two Scanners, you should use one for both int and String inputs.

Comment: alright, the 2 dimensional arrays worked! thanks!